# PyOpenGL: set glColor = constantly changing vector

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

Alright, I've posted once about this before, but I'm getting a different issue from my original dilemma.
I have a variable called

```
current_color
```

that get's converted from a color

i.e: Green

into a vector

i.e: (0, 128, 0)

so current_color = (0, 128, 0) (this variable changes every quarter of a second)

So I have a cube, and I want it to change color when the variable

```
current_color
```

changes.

This is what my cube looks like:

```
def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in surfaces:
        x = 0
        for vertex in surface:
            x += 1
            glColor3fv(current_color[x])
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()
```

Whenever I run the program I get this:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bootyman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Bootyman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bootyman\PycharmProjects\vvis\seperateenvtest.py", line 94, in vvis_graphics
    Cube()
  File "C:\Users\Bootyman\PycharmProjects\vvis\seperateenvtest.py", line 66, in Cube

 **glColor3fv(current_color[x])
IndexError: string index out of range**
```

to my understanding glColor3fv is for floats stored in a vector, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If `current_color = (0, 128, 0)`, then it has to be `glColor3fv(current_color)` But note the color channels are floating point values in the range [0.0, 1.0]. So probably you want `current_color = (0, 0.5, 0)`

Comment: so if that's the case, and I have a dictionary that's full of colors like so:
    ALICEBLUE = (240, 248, 255)

    ANTIQUEWHITE = (250, 235, 215)

    ANTIQUEWHITE1 = (255, 239, 219)

then I need to change all of those to floating point values?

Comment: No you can do something like `glColor3f(current_color[0]/255.0,current_color[1]/255.0,current_color[2]/255.0)`

Comment: @RichardWenzel my bet s that `current_color` has just 3 elements `(r,g,b)` and in the loop you are accessing by `[x]` which will go way over index `2` if the case then change your call to `glColor3fv(current_color)`. if you got array of colors instead than the code is OK.  Another problem is that you are incrementing `x` before usage. Not a python coder but arrays are usually accessed from index `0` so that might lead to another access violation ...

Comment: Alright so all of this is working, but it doesn't redraw to the new color...

Comment: What does the rest of the main loop look like? Are you clearing the screen each frame with `glClear` for example as well as swapping the buffers to update the contents of the screen once you have redrawn your scene?